# How to get rid of this red line in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open eclipse jee.
2. Open any file containing text.

Error Screenshot:
[image: Red line in Editor]

Eclipse Version:
[image: Eclipse version]

Comment: Looks like the "print margin" - Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors - "show print margin"

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, that the print margin. I added it as an answer, but if you also add it as an answer, I'll delete mine since you were faster than me, [at least on SO](https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1405906591019380742). ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's the [**print margin**](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-texteditorprefs.htm), which **has been enabled by default** in the *Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers* (**jee**) **2021-06**, but not in other IDE packages.

To turn it off, in *Window* (macOS: *Eclipse*) *> **Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors*** uncheck the checkbox ***Show print margin***.

For details see [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1406896900381491200).