# How to hide Eclipse DevStyle vertical line (page separator?)

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

I run Eclipse-2021-06 with DevStyle in Dark Mode and when editing files I get this annoying vertical line (see screenshot, surrounded by red rectangle). I assume it is a page separator, i.e. if I printed that java file, that's where a new page to the right would begin. Is there a way to hide this line?

[Vertical line in eclipse editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZSgr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you are seeing is the print margin, which is enabled by default in Eclipse 2021-06.
You can disable it from here: Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > uncheck ‘Show print margin’ and apply the changes. You can also tweak the color of the line from the ‘Appearance color options’ section in the above page.

Comment: Here is the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68429488/6505250